# Using multiple Swagger definitions at root of object

Tags: yaml, swagger

I am trying to create a Response Object that looks like this:

(simplified for example)

```
{
"data1": "1234"
"data2" : "445"
}
```

I have 2 definitions:

```
 obj1: 
  type: object 
  properties: 
   data1:
    type: string

 obj2:
  type: object 
  properties: 
   data2:
    type: string
```

Then a 3rd definition that looks like this:

```
  Main:
    type: object
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/ob1"
      - $ref: "#/definitions/obj2"
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to merge both Obj1 and Obj 2 at the base of the Main object

The Swagger UI show the following

```
Responses

Code    Description Schema
200  Success ⇄  
Main {
all of:
obj1 { }
obj2 { }
}
```

What I'm unclear about is if it will set these objects at the root or if its stating 2 objects will be in the response???

I'm assuming its correct, hoping someone can confirm.

Comment: you can use allOf from openapi v3. More details in the link below: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

Answer (score 1):

`Swagger allows combining and extending model definitions using the allOf property of JSON Schema, in effect offering model composition. allOf takes in an array of object definitions that are validated independently but together compose a single object.`

According to this - Swagger UI shows two objects which in fact be composed into one object with combined properties. You can try it by yourself:

```
StringObj:
  type: object
  properties:
    stringId:
      type: string
IntegerObj:
  type: object
  properties:
    integerId:
      type: integer
Composed:
  description: A representation of a dog
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/definitions/StringObj'
  - $ref: '#/definitions/IntegerObj'
```

If you use `Composed` in - for example - body of your method and use `try this operation` Swagger creates json:

```
{
  "stringId": "aaa",
  "integerId": 123
}
```